# Gan Eden has gates and keepers?

Tags: talmud-gemara, gan-eden, heaven

According to Wikipedia:

*In the Talmud there are two types of spiritual places called "Garden in Eden". The first is rather terrestrial, of abundant fertility and luxuriant vegetation, known as the "lower Gan Eden" (gan = garden). The second is envisioned as being celestial, the habitation of righteous, Jewish and non-Jewish, immortal souls, known as the "higher Gan Eden". The rabbis differentiate between Gan and Eden. Adam is said to have dwelt only in the Gan, whereas Eden is said never to be witnessed by any mortal eye.*

Is it mentioned anywhere that the Garden in Eden "whether the higher or the lower Gan Eden" has gates or keepers warders to take care of it?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Genesis 2:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.15?lang=bi&aliyot=0), Man was placed in the Garden to take care of it, so he was apparently its first keeper. Later, after Adam and Chavah are kicked out of the Garden, guards were placed at the entrance ([Genesis 3:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> "He drove the man out, and stationed east of the garden of Eden the cherubim and the fiery ever-turning sword, to guard the way to the tree of life."